# convergence in mean square

Tags: convergence-divergence, stochastic-calculus

$$\frac{(-1)^n}{n\sqrt{\omega}}$$ when w belongs to (0,1].

Does it converge a.s or m.s? I was able to proof that in converges in probability to zero (therefore converging in distribution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every $\omega \in (0,1]$ the limit is $0$. Hence your sequence converges almost surely (which implies it converges in probability and in distribution) (taking Lebesgue measure as the base measure). Convergence in mean square to $0$ means $\int_0^{1} |\frac {(-1)^{n}} {n\sqrt {\omega}}|^{2} \to 0$. But this integral is $\infty$ for  very $n$ so mean square convergence is not true.

Comment: Doesn't this prove that it doesn't converge to 0 in m.s, but maybe it converges to another value or Random Variable?

Comment: @GW1997 If a sequence of random variables converges in mean square to $Y$ and almost surely to $X$ the necessarily $X=Y$  almost surely. This follows from a theorem which says that there is a subsequence of the sequence which converges to $Y$  almost surely. So. we cannot have mean square convergence to some other random variable.

Comment: @GW1997 Beside there is  no question of random variables coverging in mean square to any random variable if they don't even have  a finite second moment. In this case the second moment is $\infty$.

Comment: What if couldn't rely on the knowledge of the second moment? How do you prove that the sequence above doesn't converge in m.s? I'm asking because my textbook hasn't talked about second moments yet so there must exist another way to prove the lack of convergence

Comment: @GW1997 $X_n \to X$ in mean square means $E|X_n-X|^{2} \to 0$. If $E|X_n-X|^{2}$ is not finite you cannot have means square convergence

Comment: How do you that $$E|Xn - X|^2$$ isn't finite? I apologize if this is already clear

Comment: If $E|X_n-X|^{2} <\infty$ and $E|X_m-X|^{2}<\infty$ for some random variable $X$ then $E|X_n-X_m|^{2} \leq 2(E|X_n-X|^{2}+E|X_m-X|^{2}<\infty$ by the inequality $(a+b)^{2} \leq 2(a^{2}+b^{2})$. But you can see that $E|X_n-X_m|^{2}= \infty$ whenever $n \neq m$.

Comment: Got it! Thank you for explaining!

Comment: @GW1997 If you are satisfied you could consider clicking on the tick mark to the left of my answer to approve it.